# How to find the second minimum log in time per each user id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working on a SQL query on BigQuery and trying to find the second minimum login time for each user id.

| User_id | LoginTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-06 08:45:17 |
| 1 | 2022-11-07 09:52:27 |
| 1 | 2022-11-08 02:08:54 |
| 2 | 2022-11-04 08:10:38 |
| 2 | 2022-11-07 16:46:34 |
| 2 | 2022-11-18 01:26:53 |

And I want to find the following result.

| User_id | SecondLoginTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-07 09:52:27 |
| 2 | 2022-11-07 16:46:34 |

Could anyone help me figure out how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `RANK()` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY LoginTime) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT User_id, LoginTime AS SecondLoginTime
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 2
ORDER BY User_id;
```

Note that, depending on the behavior you want if ties can happen, you may want to use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()`.